# How to explain channel block mechanism to golang beginners?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm a golang beginner and I've encountered some trouble when learning channel and go routine. One of my stuck point is how golang channel block mechanism works. In [golang tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2), it says `By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready.` I did some experiments with my understanding, and met the result, `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`. This hints didn't really give me much knowledge about how the error happens. I've googled it, but almost every article I got is about the deep mechanism of channel, or it assumes the reader understanding the single word `block` already gave out all the information.

But as a beginner I have many doubts, like:

- Can same go-routine execute channel read operation after it writes to the  channel?
- If a channel blocked, can other go-routine still send message to it?
- If a go-routine tries to send message to a blocked channel, what will happen? Will it throw an error, or nothing happened, or?

Below is one of my test which confuses me. (According to my knowledge, main func is a go-routine and I think it's the same one across its execution)

```
package main

import "time"

func chanWrite(s string, ch chan string) {
    ch <- s
    println("write", s)
}

func chanRead(ch chan string) {
    println("read", <- ch)
}

// main func 1
func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go chanWrite("A", ch)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

// main func 1 didn't throw error


// main func 2(modify main func 1 and then execute it)
func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    chanWrite("A", ch)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
// main func 2 throw error: "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"
```

What I saw in this test is in some condition, when I wrote things to the channel without reading it, I got `fatal error`, and sometimes nothing happened. (such like in main func 1).

**So, can somebody explain how channel block works in a simple and inspiring way so that golang beginners can understand it easily?**

Answer (score 2):

A goroutine can block waiting for a channel to be ready for send or receive, but the channel itself is never in a "blocked" state.

The first program does not panic because the main function executes to the end and terminates the program.

> Can same go-routine execute channel read operation after it writes to the channel?

No, if the channel is unbuffered (the default). For an unbuffered channel, a sending goroutine blocks until a receiving goroutine is ready.

A single goroutine cannot execute send and receive at the same time.  If there's only one goroutine sending to the channel, the goroutine blocks forever.

> If a channel blocked, can other go-routine still send message to it?

A goroutine can send a value to a channel at any time before the channel is closed.  A goroutine can block waiting for the channel to be ready for send.

> If go-routine trys to send message to a blocked channel, what will happened? Will it through an error, or nothing happened, or?

A goroutine can block waiting for the channel to be ready.  The channel itself is not in a blocked state.

Answer (score 1):

A channel does not "block". A read or write operation on a channel may block.

For an unbuffered channel (which is what you have above): a write operation will block the writing goroutine until another goroutine is ready to read from that channel. When the reading goroutine is ready to read (i.e. executes <-ch), then the write and read take place, and both goroutines continue running.

For a buffered channel: a write will not block as long as the channel buffer is not full. Similarly, a read will not block if there is something to read from the channel.

As for your questions:

1. If the channel in question is unbuffered, the write operation will block, because a write operation can continue only if another goroutine is reading from the channel. So the goroutine will not progress to read from the channel. If this is a buffered channel and if the channel is not full, the same goroutine may write to the channel and read from it.
2. If a goroutine is waiting to write to a channel, and another goroutine comes to write to it, it will block as well until another goroutine reads fro the channel.
3. If a goroutine tries to write to a channel that is full, it will block until another goroutine can read from the channel.